# IOException when starting a process

Tags: java

I am trying to run some Mercurial commands from a java program. I build my `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder` like this:

```
final ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("hg", "log");

procBuilder.directory(new File("/Users/feuerball/workspace/www"));

final Process proc = procBuilder.start();
```

The folder `www` contains a Mercurial repository, `hg` is installed and in the systems `PATH`. But my program throws an exception when I start the process. This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hg" (in directory "/Users/feuerball/workspace/www"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at de.feuerball.tests.Test.main(Test.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 1 more
```

Why do I get this error?

**Update**

To show that the directory does exist, I have changed the code a little bit:

```
final File repo = new File("/Users/feuerball/workspace/www");

System.out.println("Directory? " + repo.isDirectory());
System.out.println("Readable? " + repo.canRead());
System.out.println("Writable? " + repo.canWrite());

final ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("hg", "log");
procBuilder.directory(repo);

final Process proc = procBuilder.start();
```

Now here is the proof:

```
Directory? true
Readable? true
Writable? true
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hg" (in directory "/Users/feuerball/workspace/www"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at de.brushmate.tests.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` doesn't use the env variable PATH, it can't find "hg", you need to specify the absolute path to "hg" (like /usr/bin/hg if you're using Linux)

Comment: Is there no way to tell Java or the `ProcessBuilder` about my `PATH`?

Comment: @feuerball I'm afraid you can't, a not easy workaround (if you insist in using PATH) is to get its value: `Map<String, String> env = System.getenv(); String path = env.get("PATH");` then split it using ":" as separator (ugly step and error-prone) and finally try with every posibility. It is much better to use the absolute path to your executable, which you can have by executing in the command line `which hg`

Comment: Okay, I think I will use a properties file for the path then. Thanks for your help!